# eclipse: how to create an applet?

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I have finished writing my applications, and would like to deploy it as a Java applet.

How can I start this ?

Additionally, how would you deploy it on html page, and pass an argument to the Java applet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you merely wish to deploy an app. from a web site, look into [Java Web Start](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_webstart.xml).  JWS can launch a standard frame (or applet) direct from a link on a web page, and has much fewer hassles, while providing many benefits.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a tutorial on how to create an applet in eclipse. http://www.roseindia.net/eclipse/applet-eclipse.shtml